# Convert a date seperated with slash to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, web

I have got a problem with JavaScript. I have a date string say "30/05/2014" in a variable . But when i try to pass it as AJAX call URL like this

```
URL : http://www.myurl.com?travelDate=30/05/2013
```

But the URL called such that http://www.myurl.com?travelDate=0.0029791459781529296

But I need the date pattern DD/MM/YYYY pattern.Do anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add the code where you construct the URL?

Comment: What @TejasKale said... Because `30 / 5 / 2013 == 0.00298062593`. Instead of concatenating the strings, your code is calculating _"day divided by month divided by year"_

Comment: Use [*encodeURIComponent*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.4): `'http://www.myurl.com?travelDate=' + encodeURIComponent('30/05/2013')`.

Answer (score 0):

first replace '/' by '_' then append date to the URL

```
var date = "30/05/2014"
date = date.replace(/\//g,'_');
```

output: 30_05_2014

http://www.myurl.com?travelDate=30_05_2014

then in java you can replace '_' by '/' to get back the date value again. then you can do your further processing

```
String date = "30_05_2014";
date = date.replaceAll("_", "/");
```

Output: 30/05/2014